# How to hide subfolder when using Web.config for subdomains?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, subdomain, rewrite, web.config

I have FTP access to my ASP.NET Websapce (IIS 7) and I route subdomains with a Web.config in the web root folder. She looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="route www and emtpy requests" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?example.com" />
                        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/www/" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\www\{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="route to blog" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog.example.com$" />
                        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/blog/" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\blog\{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As you can see i have two folders in my root directory: **"www"** and **"blog"**.
When i now enter **"blog.example.com"** everythink is working fine, but when i click a link i will go to **"blog.example.com/blog"**

What can I do to prevent this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

Its because your redirecting to blog.foo.com/blog, you need to redirect to the FQDN.(foo.con/blog instead.

Comment: I'm not realy understand what you mean, could you please make a example rule?

Comment: redirect blog.(mydomain).com to mydomain.com/blog

Comment: But than its not a subdomain anymore?

Comment: your users can access it via subdooain